# Make $(z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2)(z^2+c^2)$ into complete square form?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

How can I make $(z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2)(z^2+c^2)$ into complete square form?
Consider $z$ to be complex number, $a$, $b$, and $c$ to be constants.

What I tried: I have expanded the polynomial but I don't have any clue about making it into the complete square form, other than
$$x+ax = \left(x + \frac {a}{2}\right)^2 - \frac {a^2}{4}$$

If not a complete square, is it possible to write the above polynomial in any reduced form?

Comment: Maybe you can use the identity identity :
$$(z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2)=(z^2-ab)^2+(a-b)^2z^2 $$

Comment: @FreeMind You really need to be more specific about what you mean by "complete square".  What is your actual goal?  For most applications, the form $(z^2 + a^2)(z^2+b^2)(z^2+c^2)$ is as simple as you can make it, so why do you want to complete the square?

Comment: @ErickWong Someone told me it can be reduced to another form. I am just trying to find the most reduced form. By complete square I mean the whole thing should be in one parentheses power two.

Comment: @FreeMind As Elaqqad hints, it can be written in the form $(\cdots)^2 + (\cdots)^2$, but it I believe it's provably impossible to write it as a single polynomial squared.  There will always be a remainder term.  As I said, for most uses I can imagine, the form you have it in is already the most reduced form, but "reduced" really depends on what you're using it for.

Comment: @ErickWong Is it possible to take advantage of $|z|^2 = z\bar z$?

Comment: @FreeMind Sure, but that would be writing it as $|P|^2$, not $(P)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sixth degree polynomial that can be written as $P^2$ can have at most three distinct zeros in the complex plane, specifically the zeros of $P$. Your polynomial has zeros $\pm ia, \pm ib, \pm ic$, which are all distinct in the generic case.

So the answer is no, this cannot be written as a complete square.

The only "more reduced" form that I can think of is 
$$
(z+ia)(z-ia)(z+ib)(z-ib)(z+ic)(z-ic)
$$